# How to make a bootable ISO from Android CLI? (via Termux or Proot-distro)

Tags: boot, android-x86, termux

I know there are some .APK apps that do it, but none seems to work for me (but if you have any suggestions, I'll try).

I have LineageOS on my PC. So, my question is How to make a bootable stick with in Termux?
Which commande should I install?

I have also installed some proot-distros installed (I'm currently testing them as a newbie), so, could I use one of them? Should I try to use Multisystem?

I had good success with Multisystem, so if I could use it either as their bootable ISO or their .deb with success, if you think it's possible, I'll listen to your suggestions.

EDIT: As asked, I add some precisions about my goal.
I'm trying to install a Multisystem ISO (or as a .deb package)
Installation inside a distro, as a .deb package: http://liveusb.info/dotclear/index.php?pages/install
Multisystem as an ISO here: https://sourceforge.net/projects/multisystem/files/iso/

I need to resize my /system partition, and If I can, create a /recovery partition, so I need to use Gparted ISO. And on the same USB, I need Also a recovery if my AndroidX86 fails to start.
So I decided to install Multisystem to make a multi-ISO stick.

Comment: Have you considered using `dd`? For an Ubuntu ISO, you can try [this](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/creating-a-bootable-ubuntu-usb-stick-on-a-debian-linux/).  Also, it is best if you mention the link of the ISO you are using to make your USB bootable. *How to make a bootable stick with in Termux?* -- this makes things unclear. A stick is useless in itself in terms of making it bootable. What you are trying to boot from it is what matters.

Comment: Could you make it an answer? I think it worths it, I will try your method. I'll add the ISO link.